# Sharepoint 2013 add button to Infopath 2013 form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath

Since I am new to working with Sharepoint 2013, I have the following questions to ask you about Infopath 2013 and possibly SharePoint Desinger 2013:

1. Yesterday I created a custom list in my 'test area of SharePoint' and opened the list in Infopath 2013 to see what the form would look like. Now I have alot more columns and edits to add to the list. I am planning to add more columns to the list when I am in my 
   'test area' and then make cosmetic changes to the form using Infopath 2013. I am thinking that if I continue this way, I may lose some edit changes I have made using Infopath 2013. Thus can you tell me the best way to add more columns to the list and/or modify the 
   existing columns and not lose the edit changes that I made using Infopath 2013?
2. The infopath 2013 form does not contain any buttons to click. I need a button to show up for every user to click so that a workflow can be started. Do I need some kind of a task list(action)? Thus can you tell me how to add this type of a button to the form?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to do the following:

1) Create a SharePoint Custom List

2) Click the ribbon button Customize on Infopath (sorry for the picture my infopath is in Spanish, and remember to use IE)
[image: InfoPath Button]

3) On infopath you can add all the fields that you need, just try to use CamelCase for the field names

[image: InfoPath Add New]

4) To add a button click on home ribbon Button or Picture Button (this one allows you to add a custom image button)
[image: add InfoPath Button]

5) Click on the button and a the rules that you need to provide the required functionality like: 
[image: Simple Rule]

There are a  lot of things that you can do with info path forms, hope this helps you to get started.

Comment: Is there a way to use a button for a user to click on to manually start a workflow? If so, can you show me how to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Yes there is a way to accomplish this. You need to create a status workflow on sharepoint desinger and then a variable inside the form so every time you submit the form it changes the status on the list and then the workflow gets executed. Right now I'm not on my workstation so I cannot upload screenshots of how to do it, but maybe tomorrow I can upload them.

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you can upload a picture of a status workflow that would help a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Hi I'm working on a complete example of how to accomplish many common things on workflows so I decided to create a blog entry whit all this information, as soon as I finish it I let you know

Comment: Hi I'm really sorry for the delay, I had a lot of work these days, anyway here is a detailed example on how to link an Infopath Form with a SP workflow [http://kaleidosoft.com.mx/2015/01/infopath-tip-formulario-con-flujo-de-trabajo/](http://kaleidosoft.com.mx/2015/01/infopath-tip-formulario-con-flujo-de-trabajo/) I'm working on the English version but the screenshots are really clear, If you have any doubt let me know.