# InfoPath customize action when button is clicked

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, infopath-rules

In an InfoPath 2013 form that accesses a custom list, I would like to add functionality to the form. When a user clicks on a button, checkbox, and/or some other item, I would like  to change a 'status' value in the workflow. Basically when the item is clicked, I would like to start that part of the workflow.

Thus can you tell me if I can place a button in the 'Ribbon' that is auto generated by InfoPath and/or if I can place a button somewhere else on the form?

If so can you tell me the following when the user clicks the button and that  starts the workflow?

1. Can I place the button on the ribbon? (Can you let me know if this option is possible and how to accomplish this goal?)
2. Can I place the button just somewhere on the form?
3. Can I place the button in the ribbon and somewhere on the form?

Of the option you chose, can you tell me how to accomplish that goal?

Answer (score 0):

1) do not use the ribbon for this, use custom infopath buttons

2) check this [Custom Buttons](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126385/sharepoint-2013-add-button-to-infopath-2013-form/126412#126412)

3) Here is the link to a detailed example of Infopath Workflows [InfoPath Post](http://kaleidosoft.com.mx/2015/01/infopath-tip-formulario-con-flujo-de-trabajo/) I'm working on the English version but the screenshots are really clear, If you have any doubt let me know.